# Problem printing a data in thymeleaf template with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can't print a String on a thymeleaf template, which I pass from a Spring boot controller. It is a very basic example. When I running the project there seems to be no error. From the only method of the controller, I pass a String to print in the template, but it does not appear printed. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Thymeleaf file

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<p> texto de prueba </p>
<p th:text="${dato}"></p>
<p> otro texto de prueba </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and Controller Spring boot file

```
package com.jumpering.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ProductController{

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {

   model.addAttribute("dato", "mensaje aleatorio");
   return "index";
   }
}
```

and my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.jumpering</groupId>
<artifactId>raconet</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>raconet</name>
<description>Lo Raconet</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My pom.xml also refers to DB drivers because in the project I will use MySql databases.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("dato", "mensaje aleatorio");
   return "index";
}
```

, Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Example</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <bootstrap.version>4.2.1</bootstrap.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does the index page open but not printing?

Comment: Yes, the index is opened, but not show the content of "dato". Only show "texto prueba" and "otro texto de prueba"

Comment: Did you add                                                                                            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Yes exist in my pom.xml,         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: And the HTML page under `resources/templates/index.html` ?

Comment: I have tried it right now and printing: `mensaje aleatorio`

Comment: then maybe it is a problem of my configuration. Maybe Tomcat?

Comment: Are you using Spring boot?

Comment: Yes I do, and MySql 8.0. IDE Intellij

Answer (score 0):

After hanging around, I discovered that the problem was in the location of the application's 'main' file:

[image]

Notice that the 'main' file is inside the 'com.example.demo' package. Here is the problem. For it to work, the file 'main' must be in 'com.example'. I don't know why this happens, but that's how the code works for me.

[image]

It is in this location of the 'main' file, and here the code does work.

Answer (score 0):

your html should have  at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE>    
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
    <p> texto de prueba </p>
    <p th:text="${dato}"></p>
    <p> otro texto de prueba </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```